# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager item match_parent width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recycler view like this :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And item like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:linksClickable="true" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm doing this in the code to have a grid with 2 columns :

```
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        _recycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

I want that each item take the "match_parent" space available, and it's not the case! Each item take the half space available. How to do to have item with a width="match_parent" and the possibility to scroll horizontally?

I want something like this :

```
 screen

|------|

  ITEM1    - ITEM2
  ITEM3   - ITEM4
```

Comment: you want both horizontal and vertical scroll ?

Comment: nop, because I want to show all the content without vertical scroll. I just want to offer the horizontal scroll to show items "hidden". (because if each item is showed in match parent, must scroll to see others)

Comment: So yo want to display one item at a time ? and scroll horizontally ?

Comment: Nop we can see fews items. Each items have to take the all available in "width" so I can have 3,4,5 items on the view, I don't know, it depends the height of each view. I want to scroll horizontally to show items contained in the column 2. (which is hidden because the items of the colum 1 gets all the width available in the view screen)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match parent horizontally and have it scroll horizontally, you have to switch one of them around. To achieve what you want you would have to use a something like FiewFlipper or tabs.

Comment: I don't understand why! Table layout can show items which match°_parent and scroll horizontally. I wanted to use a recycler view instead of my table layout for performance but... if it's not possible :(

Comment: You say you don't need vertical scrolling, meaning you are only going to have a few items in your grid? If so RecyclerView won't increase performance, it only helps when you have a list that is larger than can fit on the screen at any one time.

Comment: Nop, I don't WANT to allow vertical scrolling, I'm showing all the content because it's a specific case, so yes, Recyclerview will increase performance I think :(